# How do I build a text 3 question input quiz that redirects on correct answer using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, json

StackOverflow community. I am hoping to help out a friend by fixing the script below to enable it to run.

I can see a few errors myself but it's my first time writing more than echo "Hello World!";.

I would like 3 questions and if all correct, a congradulate box apears "you got all 3 correct, move on" then a redirect to another page.

If incorrect, "Incorrect, try again!"

I also tried to add upper or lower case for the answers but failed.

Can anyone help me tidy it up and enable it to function or point me in the right direction.

Many thanks in advance.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
        <title>JavaScript fill in the blanks</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="CRYPTIC RESCUE MISSION">
Q.The answer is Question 1?
<br><input type="text" name="q1"><br></br>

Q.The answer is Question 2?
<br><input type="text" name="q2"><br></br>

Q.The answer is Question 3?
<br><input type="text" name="q3"><br></br>

<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="myfun()">
</form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

function myfun(){
        var v1=document.myform.value;
        var v2=document.myform.q2.value;
        var v3=document.myform.q3.value;
        
        var score=0;
        
        if(v1=="Answer 1"){
                score++;
        }
        if(v2=="Answer 2"){
                score++;
        }
        if(v3=="Answer 3"){
                score++;
        }
        
        alert("you got all "+score"correct, move on");
        location.href = 'https://google.co.uk';
        
        else
        alert("Incorrect, try again!");
        
        
}
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: You typed `var v1=document.myform.value;`, but what is `myform`? It's not mentioned anywhere else. If you were trying to access the form element from JavaScript, you should add `id = "myform"` to the form element, and then `var v1=document.getElementById("myform").value;` in the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this should solve your problem. ( Please compare your submission with this answer so you can see what you where missing

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>JavaScript fill in the blanks</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="CRYPTIC RESCUE MISSION">
      Q.The answer is Question 1?
     <br><input type="text" name="q1"><br></br>

     Q.The answer is Question 2?
    <br><input type="text" name="q2"><br></br>

    Q.The answer is Question 3?
    <br><input type="text" name="q3"><br></br>

    <input type="button" value="submit" onclick="myfun()">
  </form>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">

  function myfun(){
    var v1 = document.getElementsByName('q1')[0].value;
    var v2 = document.getElementsByName('q2')[0].value;
    var v3 = document.getElementsByName('q3')[0].value;
    
    var score=0;
    
    if(v1=="Answer 1"){
            score++;
    }
    if(v2=="Answer 2"){
            score++;
    }
    if(v3=="Answer 3"){
            score++;
    }
    
    if (score == 3) {
        alert("you got all " +score + " correct, move on");
        window.location.href = 'https://google.co.uk';
    } 
    else {
        alert("Incorrect, try again!");
    }
    
    
  }
</script>


</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses. As a first time user to the site, it's much appreciated and I am impressed. It all makes sense and I can see what I missed.

Comment: Not a problem. Welcome to the Stackoverflow community. Its always nice to get an answer but its always in your best interest to understand the answer so you learn and can help others later.

Comment: Couldn’t agree more, I am not a fan of copy and paste. This was a little advanced for me but still learning. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

```js
function myfun(){
        var v1=document.getElementById('form').elements[0].value;
        var v2=document.getElementById('form').elements[1].value;
        var v3=document.getElementById('form').elements[2].value;
         console.log('came',v1,v2,v3)

        var score=0;
        
        if(v1=="Answer 1"){
                score++;
        }
        if(v2=="Answer 2"){
                score++;
        }
        if(v3=="Answer 3"){
                score++;
        }
        if(score === 3) {
          alert('Yes correct')
        } else {
          alert('Incorrect, try again!')
        }
        
}
```

```html
<body>
<form id="form" name="CRYPTIC RESCUE MISSION">
Q.The answer is Question 1?
<br><input type="text" name="q1"><br></br>

Q.The answer is Question 2?`enter code here`
<br><input type="text" name="q2"><br></br>

Q.The answer is Question 3?
<br><input type="text" name="q3"><br></br>

<input type="button" value="submit" onclick="myfun()">
</form>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

you didn't define Answer1,2,3 therefore there is actually no answer to your question. e.g, what does  The answer is Question 1? mean rewrite and define the answers and your code should work

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30890113)